# Migrate application running in Windows 2000 server to windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008

Currently we are running an application build in VB6,ASP,Commerce Server2000 and Sql Server 2000. This application is running in Windows 2000 server.

Now we are planning to migrate Windows server 2000 to Windows 2008.

Will this application run in Windows 2008 or do we need to upgrade this application to dotnet and Sql 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, it should NOT work, sorry.

Mostly check whether Commerce Serve r2000 and SQL Server 2000 are supported under Windows Server 2008... I dont think they are.